# Recommend good remote desktop product for Windows Server

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

We find that on our new servers VNC runs very slow and the screen does not update correctly

When I connect to or disconnect from servers using MSTSC, it sometimes causes our running app to abort with an exception somewhere in the .NET code. Also, it's annoying to have to login to the box each time.

Can anyone recommend a decent remote admin solution which does not max out the CPU, or make your apps unstable?

Comment: Just a minor point but isn't MSTCS using RDP not VNC as the protocol?

Comment: Try adjusting the "Experience" tab in the settings of the MSTSC connection to optimize for a lower bandwidth connection and see if that makes a difference in the perceived speed.  This will disable things like the desktop background, font smoothing, desktop composition, etc.

Comment: We've tried MSTSC/RDP and VNC, both have drawbacks.

Thanks to all for the suggestions. I was also going to look at RADMIN. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might also like to see about either getting that app fixed or replace it with a less buggy one. It clearly has some problems. Additionally, if it should be running as a service to avoid log ons/ log offs affecting it.

Answer (score 6):

Dameware is fairly decent, but I'd really try to fix your MSTSC problems and use that.

Comment: +1 for Dameware. You only pay for the management console and not the agents and the agents can be pushed to each server, so no manual install is needed.

Comment: +1 for fixing the underlying problem, this is NOT normal.  I'd be concerned.

Comment: @Kara: It may be perfectly normal for the application to crash in a TS environment. Not every application is written for and not every developer codes for Terminal Services.

Comment: @joeqwerty I don't think ignoring the underlying problem will help, this may manifest with Dameware was well, its unknown.  User might be able to log in as /admin (/console pre 2008 TS) to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I've been always using RDP for windows servers. I don't think anything beats it in terms of speed and availability. So definitely try to figure out why isn't it working properly.

Answer (score -1):

I use No Machines NX server and client and find they work great.  Like you are sitting in front of the machine even across the internet.  They also work great in a mixed environment as they have server and client systems for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: NX version 4 will have a Windows server component, but the current version (3.5) supports Windows *clients* only. Server components are available for Linux and Solaris.

Comment: You are correct I only used it to connect with Linux servers using both the Linux and Windows client I did not realize that there was no Windows server